# Webpack: include css and svg to html

Tags: css, svg, webpack

Sorry for this question, but I really cant't understand.
Svg and styles not loaded in projects. Svg in Network console loaded on this adress:  http://localhost:9000/%7B'./images/Browser.svg'%7D

I see extra character..

My webpack conf:

```
{
mode: 'development',
entry: __dirname + '/IE/index.js',
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
},
target: ['web', 'es5'],
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, './IE/ieMock.html'),
    }),
],

module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },

        { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-inline-loader' },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            {
                                // targets: {
                                //     ie: '11',
                                // },
                            },
                        ],
                    ],
                },
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

};

ieMock.html:

```
 <!doctype html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>Предупреждение</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IE/index.css">
    <link href="./src/assets/styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./src/assets/styles/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<main>
<div className="ie-support-container">
    <div className="ie-support-container__el">
      
        <p>
            Переходите на ЯндексБраузер.
         
        </p>
    </div>

    <div className="ie-support-container__el">
    <div className="browser_label">
        <img src={'./images/Browser.svg'} />
        <span>Браузер</span>
    </div>
    <div className="browser_label">
        <img src={'./images/YandexBrowser.svg'} />
        <span>Яндекс Браузер</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</main>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import './ieMock.html';
import './index.css';
```

What am I doing wrong? Why svg loaded with extra character?

Comment: Those extra characters are the brackets you have in your html file. The URL decodes to {'./images/Browser.svg'}. Try removing the brackets.

Comment: now there is a problem with css..